# Determining distances between many individual points using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, point, proximity

I am trying to find an easy way to calculate linear distances between an array of points.  I have an array of points that border a rectangular area that represent a dewatering well array.  As of now, I simply export the XY Coordinates and drop them into an excel sheet to calculate this but was hoping an all-in-one use might be possible within ARCGIS 10.  I need each point to have a distance to every other point in the array.

Example.  5 points, P1 to P5.  Need distance from P1 to P2, P1 to P3, P1 to P4, etc. etc.

Is there a simple solution that I am overlooking?  NEAR function seems to only let me get one distance and I'm hoping I don't have to create individual shapefiles for each well point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sounds like a good case for the [Point Distance tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Point_Distance/00080000001r000000/). Simply use the same point feature class for the input and near feature class inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the [Point Distance](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/analysis-toolbox/point-distance.htm) tool to calculate the distances between one point and many other points, it returns a table with the distances.

Since all your points are all in one array, I'm not sure what the best approach to process them in one go is. Are you familiar with using ModelBuilder? You may be able to iterate through each point in the array to create two layers (the point and all the others) and use those as inputs for the Point Distance tool, but I have a feeling there is a more efficient way.

Comment: I am not familiar with Model Builder...is that a feature within ArcGIS?

Comment: [ModelBuilder](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/analysis/geoprocessing/modelbuilder/what-is-modelbuilder-.htm) is basically a graphical interface for stringing together geoprocessing tools, accessed under the "Geoprocessing" menu button. Would take some time to get going if you haven't used it before, but it does allow you to iterate through rows in a table to do the type of analysis you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Generate Near Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/generate-near-table.htm) and limit number of output matches to QuantityOfPoints-1 with no limit of distance.